# How do I save changes made in a dictionary values to itself?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary where the values are a list of tuples.

```
        dictionary = {1:[('hello, how are you'),('how is the weather'),('okay 
        then')], 2:[('is this okay'),('maybe It is')]}
```

I want to make the values a single string for each key. So I made a function which does the job, but I do not know how to get insert it back to the original dictionary.

my function:

```
   def list_of_tuples_to_string(dictionary):
       for tup in dictionary.values():
           k = [''.join(i) for i in tup] #joining list of tuples to make a list of strings
           l = [''.join(k)] #joining list of strings to make a string
           for j in l: 
               ki = j.lower() #converting string to lower case
       return ki
```

output i want:
dictionary = {1:'hello, how are you how is the weather okay then', 2:'is this okay maybe it is'}

Comment: simply create new dictionary and put all element inside.

Comment: `for k in dictionary:
    dictionary[k] = " ".join(dictionary[k]).lower().strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done even simpler than you think, just using comprehension dicts

```
>>> dictionary = {1:[('hello, how are you'),('how is the weather'),('okay then')], 
                  2:[('is this okay'),('maybe It is')]}
>>> dictionary = {key:' '.join(val).lower() for key, val in dictionary.items()}
>>> print(dictionary)
{1: 'hello, how are you how is the weather okay then', 2: 'is this okay maybe It is'}
```

Now, let's go through the method

1. we loop through the keys and values in the dictionary with `dict.items()`
2. assign the key as itself together with the value as a string consisting of each element in the list.
3. The elemts are joined together with a single space and set to lowercase.

Comment: It;s giving me an error saying str expected and tuple found!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply overwrite the values for each key in the dictionary:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[key] = ' '.join(value)
```

Note the space in the join statement, which joins each string in the list with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in dictionary.keys():
    dictionary[i]=' '.join(updt_key.lower() for updt_key in dictionary[i])
```